# Having converting and getting data problems

Tags: java

I wrote a program that calculates Acceleration. This is how it looks:

http://prntscr.com/57yngo

when you press that button it show a dialog message that is a part of `JOptionPane`. The data you enter in fields are Strings I convert them to double by doing :

`double name = Double.valueOf(String);`

The problem is if you inserted a `String` value instead of a double value in the fields you and pressed the button that sends the acceleration total the program badly crash. I really need a solution to fix that!

If you said why did you set the inserted value as `String` I will answer
that this is the only way to do the

`Textfieldname.gettext();`

If you knew a way to get a double only from a text field please tell me it.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] values = {"1.0", "2.0", "a"};
    for (String value: values) {
        System.out.println(getValue(value));
    }
}

private static Double getValue(String valueString) {
    Double result;
    try {
        result = Double.valueOf(valueString);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        result = 0.0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to catch `NumberFormatException` to handle wrong input

Example:

`try {
        result = Double.valueOf(valueString);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //show alert and clean field or something else
    }`

Comment: How do you do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Check IF the String in the textfield can be parsed to Double before the conversion. If you expect  simple String values like 3.01 or 150 then a simple regular expression would do:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

// some stuff in your class

// and in your action listner
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+|\\d+\\.\\d+"); //digits or digits dot digits
String valueToTest = Textfieldname.gettext();
boolean canBoConverted = p.matcher(valueToTest).matches();
if (canBoConverted) {
    double name = Double.valueOf(String);
    // do something with name
} else {
    // idicate a bad input value to the user
}
```

If you need a wider range o possible values than you can use the pattern from the [Double class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Also please remember that a programmer should always validate user input against whats acceptable.

Comment: @saud Example added. Also I would argue that it is better to validate user input than to simply catch an exception.